In a github action, how to continue within a step even if a command returns a non-zero exit code
When I execute my github action, I know that a command can possibly have a non-zero return code. Howewer, I wish to continue doing stuff in that case, within the same step, which means the continue-on-error trick does not work for me as it seems to exit the current step and continue on the following ones.
Here is my code:
run: |
        BRANCH_NAME=${{ steps.set_branch_name_from_pr.outputs.BRANCH_NAME || steps.set_branch_name_from_commit.outputs.BRANCH_NAME }}
        git ls-remote --exit-code --heads https://x-access-token:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/afkl-airspace/tresorro-tresor-ro.git refs/heads/$BRANCH_NAME
        # If the branch exists, no error and we delete it
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
          git push origin --delete $BRANCH_NAME
        else
          echo "Remote branch [$BRANCH_NAME] does not exist"
        fi

The problem is that when the branch does not exist, I end up with a return code of 2 and the step exits immediately, without echoing what is in the else part.
How can I fix this issue ?

You can directly handle command with if e.g. if git ls-remote ...; then git ...; else echo ...; fi.

Also, check shellcheck's SC2181 entry on this for a detail example and rationale.

GotHub actions executes run: shell block in exit-on-error mode when running in bash, the default shell for ubuntu runners. This mode is set via set -e in bash.
In a general case when you want to proceed running bash commands without hand-crafting each command, the easiest approach is to reset this mode by using set +e. This will only apply to the current step:
- shell: bash
  run: |
      set +e

      BRANCH_NAME=${{ steps.set_branch_name_from_pr.outputs.BRANCH_NAME || steps.set_branch_name_from_commit.outputs.BRANCH_NAME }}
      git ls-remote --exit-code --heads https://x-access-token:${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com/afkl-airspace/tresorro-tresor-ro.git refs/heads/$BRANCH_NAME
      # If the branch exists, no error and we delete it
      if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        git push origin --delete $BRANCH_NAME
      else
      echo "Remote branch [$BRANCH_NAME] does not exist"
      fi


I believe you meant set +e and not set +x to disable the immediate exit mode. +x is used to disable command tracing which is the default. See the Bash's set builtin docs for more details.
